# Force a 1080p resolution on 13" MacBook Pro

Tags: display, hdmi, resolution, screen-capture

I'm trying to record a screencast using my 13" MacBook Pro (Retina, ~ 2015 model). I want to record it full screen at 1080x1920 px and I want it to be that exact resolution.

The resolution options in the Displays section of System Preferences do not have that option. Pressing option doesn't help either. I bought an app called ResolutionTab that's supposed to give more resolution options but it doesn't have a 1080x1920 px option either.

I connected a 1080p monitor using the HDMI port and used the screen mirroring option and voila my native display went into 1080x1920 px (with black bars on the top and bottom). But I don't want to keep a monitor attached to my laptop just to have this resolution option!

- I know I can record at resolutions close to 1080x1920 px but I want that exact resolution.
- I know I can crop or record a particular window or crop the screen down to 1920x1080 px, but I want to record full screen at that resolution.

Comment: Have you investigated SwitchResX?

Comment: Thank you so much @SteveChambers. I'd tried a few trial versions & open source ones none of them worked, but SwitchResX did indeed work!